# C++, How To Play Multiple Sounds At The Same Time

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, playsound

I am programming a game, in my game I have background music, that line looks like this.

```
PlaySound(TEXT("GameMusic.wav"), NULL, SND_LOOP | SND_ASYNC);
```

But sometimes when a special thing happens in the game, I want a sound effect to happen.

```
PlaySound(TEXT("SoundFX.wav"), NULL, SND_ASYNC);
```

The music stops playing once the sound effect starts, but I want them to play at the same time. The music should always be playing.

Comment: `PlaySound` cannot do this. You'd need to use a system service that provides multi-channel audio (e.g. [DirectSound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416960.aspx)). Alternatively, use an audio library, like [FMOD](http://www.fmod.org/) or [BASS](http://www.un4seen.com/).

Comment: @IInspectable Is it any way possible to do this with Multi Threading, in that case how? Or do you have any sort of solution to this problem?

Comment: `PlaySound` allows you to play one sound at any given time. The solution to your problem is to not use `PlaySound`.

Comment: PlaySound is a shell utility function. It is meant for playing little beeps to give immediate feedback. If you need to do something more complex, it will not work. If you're writing a game, use the APIs designed for game development.